# Onnx model output format

Tags: machine-learning, onnx, pmml

does onnx model support well defined output format? I have seen that many model eg PMML provides input and output fields and data types in the model itself. So the ONNX model input/output are also well defined and can it be deduced from metadata information.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When representing models using the ONNX format, the neural network is stored according to a predefined protobuf format.

This contains fields like `Graph` with all nodes sorted in topological order but also `Input` and `Output`, which contains information about the inputs and outputs of the model.

`Input` and `Output` are both `ValueInfoProto`, which holds information about the name of the input/output, and also the datatype. They have an enum with all sorts of datatypes, hence you can easily determine the datatype of the inputs and outputs.

If you want more information (I'm not sure what you mean by `format`) it of course depends: shapes might differ when using dynamic dimensions (for batch sizes of timesteps for examples). However, if you export to onnx with fixed dimension sizes you can also find this in `ValueInfoProto`.

This information can all be found in: https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/onnx/onnx.proto3